# My CSS3 isnt fading back out on my buttons

Tags: css, button, hover, fade

On [my site](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/contact/) Im using a CSS3 hover fade for my submit button. It correctly fades on hover, but when I remove the curser from the button it quickly changes back to the original color, it doesn't seem to be doing the 1 second fade back out.

```
.form-wrapper input[type=submit] {background-color:#0076A9}

.form-wrapper input[type=submit]:hover{
    background-color:#7daed3; 
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s; 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease}
```

UPDATE:

```
.social-links {
color:#0076A9;
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;}

.social-links:hover {
color:#7daed3;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ease-in-out`. See: http://css3generator.com/

```
-webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
```

For the transition to effect ALL the properties, use (for social links):

```
.social-links a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 43px;
    height: 43px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    color: #0076a9;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Apply the transition properties to it's generic state NOT in the `:hover` state. So that will be in the `.form-wrapper input[type=submit] {` selector

Comment: do you know why its not working for my icons? I just updated its css to match the submit button

Comment: EDIT: Sorry. It's because the transition is specifically effecting the background color and not the font colour. Replace "background" within the transition property to "color". To allow it to effect ALL properties, change it to "all".

Comment: i tried .social-links {
    all:#0076A9;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;
}
.social-links:hover {
    all:#7daed3;
}

Comment: still isnt fading the social icons

Comment: Change "background" to "all" like this: `-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;`

Comment: im not sure what you mean by "background", im using the css3 thats in my question

Comment: i think your still talking about the submit button. I am trying to add the same effect to my social icons at the bottom. im sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `-webkit-transition-duration:1s;` to the input without the hover in your css, like so:

```
.form-wrapper input[type=submit] {
    background-color:#0076A9;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;
}
.form-wrapper input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color:#7daed3;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/YgWYh/

Comment: i tried adding this to my social icons (see UPDATE in question), but it doesnt seem to have the fade, it just changes quickly.

Comment: i dont know how, its a template based site from squarespace

Comment: Your code should be correct though, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/YgWYh/1/ . The color of the text is animated. Do you mean that the icons are not adjusted?

Comment: is there a way to thank you both, as you both have helped me.

Comment: A +1 and the 'correct answer' are the site's ways of rewarding users, and since you've done that, you've answered that yourself!